# Oracle - Identify If Previous Record Exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have input date like this:

```
id_number    category    type   date
123          horse       big    1/1/2019
123          horse       big    1/15/2019
234          pig         small  1/20/2019
123          horse       big    2/1/2019
234          pig         medium 2/1/2019
345          dog         tiny   2/1/2019
```

For the records with the most recent date (2/1/2019), I want to retrieve which records (identified by `id_number`) are brand new and which have been updated.

Desired result:

```
id_number    category    type   date       new_or_updated
234          pig         medium 2/1/2019   updated
345          dog         tiny   2/1/2019   new
```

Record `234` is updated because `type` changed from a prior record. Record `345` is brand new because no prior records are of `id_number` `345`. Record `123` from 2/1/2019 is excluded because it is not new and it was not updated from the previous `123` record which occurred on 1/15/2019.

How do I identify new and updated records?

I have tried using `row_number()` to partition by all fields except `date` to start with, but I'm not sure where to go from there, and the `row_number()` is not working as expected because it's assigning different numbers to records with no differences outside of `date`.

```
select row_number() over (partition by id_number, category, type order by id_number),
       id_number, 
       category, 
       type, 
       date
from schema.table
```

Comment: PL/SQL is an imperative programming language, created by Oracle to work hand in hand with its version of SQL. Your question has absolutely nothing to do with PL/SQL - it is about Oracle SQL. I changed your title and tags to reflect that. Don't feel too bad - a lot of people believe (wrongly) that PL/SQL simply means "Oracle SQL".

Comment: what would you want to have output if the first row for 123 had a type of tiny instead of big?

Comment: How do you define "most recent date"? Do you mean, the "most recent date" **for each id_number**? And, why is `id = 123` not included in your output? Is it because nothing changed since the previous row (meaning: same `category` and `type` as before)?

Comment: thanks @mathguy! I would define most recent date as 2/1/2019 - that would be the report date. Any date could be the report date, so if I wanted to see which records were new or updated as of 1/20/2019, I would want to look at that record and the two before it. Correct - 123 was not changed since the previous row for a given `id_number`

Comment: @Boneist the output would remain the same because 123 did not change from the current report date (2/1/2019) and the last time 123 appears in the table.

Comment: Important question: What is your database **version** (as reported, for example, when you run `select * from v$version`)? For example, my version is 12.2.0.1.  This is important because, for example, `match_recognize` could be used for a very quick solution, but it's only available since Oracle 12.1.

Comment: 11.2.0.4.0 unfortunately. I could pull the data over to SQL Server 2012 if there is something similar there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `lag()` and some rather simple logic.  The logic for simplification is to look at the previous date, once for the id and once for the id and other columns.

I assume that "updated" means updated from the last appearance (as opposed to ever updated).  If so:

```
select t.*,
       (case when prev_id_date is null then 'New'
             when prev_id_date <> prev_ict_date or prev_ict_date is null
             then 'Updated'
             else 'Same'
        end)
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id_number) as prev_id_date,
             lag(date) over (partition by id_number, category, type) as prev_ict_date,
             row_number() over (partition by id_number order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This include the "same" records.  Of course, you can filter them out by adjusting the `where` clause to:

```
where seqnum = 1 and prev_ict_date = prev_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Find most recent row within every `ID_NUMBER` which has no previous row or previous row has different values of `category` or `type`

```
select id_number, category, type, dat
   , case when pId is null then 'new' else 'updated' end new_or_updated
from (
 select id_number, category, type, dat 
  , max(dat) over(partition by ID_NUMBER) dmax
  , lag(ID_NUMBER) over(partition by ID_NUMBER order by dat) pId
  , lag(category) over(partition by ID_NUMBER order by dat) pCategory
  , lag(type) over(partition by ID_NUMBER order by dat) pType
 from tbl
) t
where dat = dmax and (pId is null or pCategory != Category or pType !=Type );
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ea74f22ed465536eac9ae7d42b0bafa)

Comment: Elegant, succinct, and uses the method OP was attempting to use (partition by).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
WITH dat AS (SELECT  row_number() over (partition by id_number  order by DATE desc) rn
                  ,  id_number
                  ,  category
                  ,  TYPE
                  ,  date
               from schema.TABLE)
SELECT dat.*
     , CASE WHEN last_val.id_number IS NULL THEN 'new'
            WHEN last_val.category != dat.category
              OR last_val.TYPE != dat.TYPE
            THEN 'updated'
       END new_or_updated
  FROM dat 
  LEFT JOIN dat LAST_val
    ON last_val.id_number = dat.id_number
    AND last_val.rn = 2
 WHERE rn=1
   AND (last_val.id_number IS NULL 
     OR last_val.category != dat.category
     OR last_val.TYPE != dat.TYPE)
```

Comment: what is this doing `last_val.rn = 2`? and would this method then require specifying a non-equality between each field?

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass this does not work like expected your `DATE` column is not unique.. This is a non deterministic (random) sort on equal dates values with id_number "group"..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you - you are correct, date column is not unique

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass nevermind mine last comment to much assuming a id column is 99.9999999 % of all cases having a primary or unique key which in this case it not the case... But you could use Oracle's `ROWID` now i rethink about it `row_number() over (partition by id_number  order by DATE desc, ROWID DESC)` to make it deterministic (fixed) sort always..

Comment: still a little confused on how this is working/how it would be used for a specific date (i.e. which records with date 2/1/2019 are updated or new)

Comment: Sorry had to leave yesterday, the idea of the query is to get an index for id_number, sorted by date desc so the last record has to be the one with index 1 and the one prior to that has index 2, so if no record 2 exist it has to be new and otherwise if data between record 1 and 2 have changed it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. I tried to write an efficient query (rather than one that is easy to read); there is a lot to unpack, so rather than explaining everything, I will wait for you to ask for clarification on anything you don't understand.

In the query I use a WITH clause to simulate the input data, and a CTE to create the report date. I hard-coded the report date, but that can (and should) be changed to a bind variable so it can become a user input.

Then, from the input data, I read only the rows where the date is <= the report date, and then I aggregate by ID. The heart of the query is the `having` clause, where I use the `first/last` aggregate function repeatedly; read up on it first, if you are not familiar with it. (Sadly, a lot of developers aren't.) Also, in the `having` clause I use `decode` to handle the possibility that `category` or `type_` may be `null` (you didn't specifically say either way, so I wanted to handle that from the outset). I assume a change from `null` to a non-`null` value, or vice versa, is considered an "update".

Note that both **type** and **date** are Oracle keywords, they shouldn't be used as column names. I added a trailing underscore in my query.

```
with test_data (id_number, category, type_, date_) as (
  select 123, 'horse', 'big'   , to_date('1/1/2019' , 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 123, 'horse', 'big'   , to_date('1/15/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 234, 'pig'  , 'small' , to_date('1/20/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 123, 'horse', 'big'   , to_date('2/1/2019' , 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 234, 'pig'  , 'medium', to_date('2/1/2019' , 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
  select 345, 'dog'  , 'tiny'  , to_date('2/1/2019' , 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
)
, report_inputs (dt) as (
    select to_date('2/1/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
)
select t.id_number as id_number,
       max(t.category) keep (dense_rank last order by t.date_) as category,
       max(t.type_)    keep (dense_rank last order by t.date_) as type_,
       r.dt                                                    as date_,
       case when count(*) = 1 then 'new' else 'updated' end    as new_or_updated
from   test_data t join report_inputs r on t.date_ <= r.dt
group  by t.id_number, r.dt
having max(t.date_) = r.dt
       and
       (
       count(*) = 1
       or
       decode(max(t.category) keep (dense_rank last order by nullif(t.date_, r.dt) 
                                                    nulls first),
              max(t.category) keep (dense_rank last order by t.date_), 1) is null
       or
       decode(max(t.type_)    keep (dense_rank last order by nullif(t.date_, r.dt) 
                                                    nulls first),
              max(t.type_)    keep (dense_rank last order by t.date_), 1) is null 
       )
;
```

Output:

```
ID_NUMBER CATEGORY TYPE_  DATE_      NEW_OR_UPDATED
--------- -------- ------ ---------- --------------
      234 pig      medium 02/01/2019 updated
      345 dog      tiny   02/01/2019 new
```